# php error: Call to a member function fromArray() on a non-object

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I am trying to set up a "forgot password" system. User enters email and if it exists a new email is recorded and sent to the user email address entered. The user email check works ok. When trying to enter a new passord into system it does not.

The code is this:

```
..... (form is_valid and check email ok)

if(is_object($object)) {

        $newpassword = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',8)),0,8);

        $input = $form->getValues();

        $user = Doctrine::getTable('Tcc_Model_User')
            ->find($input['email']);

        $user->fromArray($input);
        $user->Password = md5($newpassword);
        $user->save();
......
email send

} else {
    $form->getElement('email')->addError('Sorry, there is no record of that email adddress.');
  }
```

the error I get is this:

```
Call to a member function fromArray() on a non-object
```

Could someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? Please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put, `$user` is not an object. It's probably either `false` or `null`, signifying that `find()` did not actually find what it was looking for.

You can see what `$user` actually is with `var_dump($user)`, and then you should read the documentation for `find` to see why it's returning that.

Comment: Or the Zend way with: Zend_Debug::dump($user);
:)

Comment: But $user id the result of `Doctrine::getTable('Tcc_Model_User')->find($input['email']);` so it's maybe a row (Zend Framework) and not an object of user's class.

Comment: @JBRTRND-DEV: There is no object of class `user` involved here. The intent of the code is clear: find the row with the specified email, update its other fields based on input, and save it. There's no `user` object logically involved in this.

Comment: @Jon : I agree, here there's no class or object "user" but what I tried to explain, is that `$user` is already affected (row, array, boolean, null) by `->find()` function, and in this way, `$user->fromArray` doesn't work.

Comment: @JBRTRND-DEV: `$user` is the *result* of the `find` function, it's not affected by it.

Comment: @Jon : It doesn't affect my explication... Hmm I'm French, so sorry for vocabulary mistake.

Comment: I am getting a bool(false) result for var_dump()

Comment: @user1120993: Then see the answer of DaveRandom, who has helpfully cited the documentation: there is no user with that email, so you are getting back `false`.

Comment: No the user exists. there is an "else" statement that tells if the user does not exists and it works ok

Comment: `find` method works on primary key no ? Email is the primary key of the table "Tcc_Model_User" ?

Comment: No it isn't....sorry i did not know that find() only works on primary key...I actually thought it could be the problem. So i guess I have to find the primary key of the email first.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_table.html#find%28%29), `Doctrine_Table::find()` (called on the line above your error) returns one of the following entities:

> Doctrine_Collection, array, Doctrine_Record or false if no result

This means that you need to check what was returned before you try and use the value, `$user`, as if it were an object exposing the `fromArray()` method.

Comment: Isn't if(is_oject($object) telling me that is returning a value?

Comment: You also need `if (is_object($user))`, since it is the `$user` variable that is triggering the error.

Comment: So as @JBRTRND-DEV says if find() only works on primary key that could be the problem. Also because the very same code works ok in other situations